# WP Nav dropdown menu is hidden in ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I'm having trouble with my nav dropdown menu hiding behind the logo and banner on my site.  I've tried changing the z-index of the nav div to 99 and then the header div to 0, but to no avail.  I'm having trouble shooting ie since I'm on a mac.  You can see the site at www.miles2give.org.  I've created a childtheme from wp theme twentytwelve and I think I may have accidentally messed something up along the way.  I don't know what code to include or I would.

Comment: what version of IE? looks fine to me.

Comment: In IE 7 and below the dropdown menu when you scroll over the nav menu goes behind the logo and the dedicate a day section

Comment: I wouldn't waste the effort to support IE 7, according to [statcounter.com](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201105-201303-bar) less than 3% of people worldwide still use it.

Comment: understandable and agree.  the only problem is with our natural target market of the cause we go after tends to be the type of people that would use ie7 more frequently

Comment: I just tried to install IE7 on my PC so that I could take a look and got the message "Sorry Internet Explorer 7 is not supported by this operating system" Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.